How to restart Splash container on ECS task
I am running 2 containers on an ECS task.

I am going to restart the splash container when it is unhealthy.
I added health check and restartPolicy to task definition but it doesn't work.
            "restartPolicy": {
                "enabled": true,
                "ignoredExitCodes": [
                    0
                ],
                "restartAttemptPeriod": 60
            },
            "healthCheck": {
                "command": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "curl -f http://localhost:8050/ || exit 1"
                ],
                "interval": 30,
                "timeout": 5,
                "retries": 3,
                "startPeriod": 10
            },

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

So it has been running for more than 60 seconds before it stopped? And you are sure it didn't return a 0 exit code when it stopped? Perhaps you should define what "it doesn't work" means in this context exactly. Your screenshot shows the container is actually running, just not responding correctly to health checks. Restart policies are for containers that exit unexpectedly, not for containers that are failing health checks.
